# Change colors of <a> tags using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to UI world.
I am facing problem in static html page.

( Please note we are not using any JS framework in my project, Please help me with pure java script code)

Now here what i want to archive is,
when i click on YAHOO, it should become orange colored and Google & Bing white
when i click on GOOGLE, it should become orange colored and Yahoo & bing white
when i click on BING, it should become orange colored and Yahoo & Google white

1) In my html page i have multiple links ,like below

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a> 
<a href="www.bing.com">Bing</a>
```

2) I have one CSS file which contains below,

```
a {text-decoration: none}
a:link, a:visited {text-decoration: none;color: white;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #FF9900;}
```

Comment: you mean like [a:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active)?

Comment: [Google it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll): Use `document.querySelectorAll([selcetor])`.

Comment: Hi, What i want is that when i click yahoo link it should persists orange color until i click any another link.

Comment: 2 steps. Basically create a class called "pressed" that is defined as orange. Then, when you click on a new link js removes any instances where the class "pressed" exists and then adds it to the recently clicked link. This is very rudimentary and you can search on google on the exact code that correlates to this problem. IF jquery WAS USED, this code would be 1 line long. Very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Edited function  // Using PURE JS // **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HW2qV/8/)**

add `id`and `onclick` attributes  to each link like:

```
<a href="#" id="googleLink" onclick="changeColor(this)">Google</a><br />
<a href="#" id="yahooLink" onclick="changeColor(this)">Yahoo</a><br />
<a href="#" id="bingLink" onclick="changeColor(this)">Bing</a>
```

change the color using a `javascript` function:

```
function changeColor(link) {
document.getElementById(link).className = "activeLink";
if(link == "googleLink"){
  document.getElementById("yahooLink").className = "";
  document.getElementById("bingLink").className = "";
   }
if(link == "yahooLink"){
  document.getElementById("googleLink").className = "";
  document.getElementById("bingLink").className = "";
   }
if(link == "bingLink"){
  document.getElementById("googleLink").className = "";
  document.getElementById("yahooLink").className = "";
   }
}
```

and style it using this `css`:

```
.activeLink{
    color: orange;
}
.activeLink:hover{
    color: orange; // *so the active link would not change color on mouse hover
}
```

Comment: We have restriction , we can not use any framework or library. It should be in Pure Javascript.

Comment: Updated my answer. Using pure JS

Comment: @n33rma If an answer has helped you solve your problem and you can accept it and can also consider voting it up. If other answers have been helpful too, you can also vote them up.

Comment: @shin: I tried voting for the answer but i get notification saying "Vote up require 15 reputation" :-(

Comment: @LOL : Thanks , i accepted the answer now ....FYI: i created SO account today itself, so i am new here too :-)

Comment: Hi Froient,

I observed that after I use this function, hover stops working after first click on any link. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi n33rma, I've updated my answer and so the fiddle demo.. hope that solves the problem :)